# javascript console log shows couple values

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, console.log

I am learning Javascript. I am creating simple budget application and I have a problem. I will pass only necessary code, to help me. So constructor is bigger, but I pass only necessary things:

```
class BudgetApp {
        constructor() {
          this.expenseListForm = document.querySelector("#expense-list");
        }

        deleteItemFromExpensesList(event) {
            Array.from(event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll(".delete-icon")).forEach((element) => {
                element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                    console.log(e.currentTarget);

                })

            })
        }
    }

eventListeners = () => {
    const budgetApp = new BudgetApp();

    budgetApp.expenseListForm.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        budgetApp.deleteItemFromExpensesList(event);
    })


}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {  
    eventListeners();
});
```

When I click `".delete-icon"` which is `<a>` tag my `console.log` show nothing, when I click second time then `console.log` shows exactly what I want, when I click third time console_log shows this `<a>` tag two times and so on. I want to get result when I click one time, console_log shows me my `<a>` tag exactly once.

What should I improve in my code? Thanks Guys.

Comment: You keep adding event handlers.

Comment: Try create of class instance, out of ```eventListenets```  function.

Comment: Ok Guys, I got it. Thanks!